# How to store 'line_items' in an array

Tags: shopify, liquid

When generating the "New order notification" mail I'd like the products to be sorted in "arrays" based on the collection name, which can be found in the product tag.

But I can't seem to store the line_item in an array.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
{% assign kaas_vleeswaren_delicatessen = "" %}

{% for line_item in order.line_items %}
  {% for tag in line_item.product.tags %}
    {% if tag == 'Kaas - vleeswaren - delicatessen Albert Heijn' %}
      {% assign kaas_vleeswaren_delicatessen = kaas_vleeswaren_delicatessen | append: line_item | append: ',' %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

{% assign kaas_vleeswaren_delicatessen = kaas_vleeswaren_delicatessen | split: ',' %}

{% for product in kaas_vleeswaren_delicatessen %}
  {{ product.title }}<br>
{% endfor %}

#=> 

{% for product in kaas_vleeswaren_delicatessen %}
  {{ product }}<br>
{% endfor %}

#=> LineItemDrop
#   LineItemDrop
#   LineItemDrop
```

When trying to look at product.title It simply returns blanks. When trying to look at product it simple returns LineItemDrop.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is not actually adding the product, it's adding its return value for line_item ("LineItemDrop" is a string, not an object):

```
{% assign kaas_vleeswaren_delicatessen = kaas_vleeswaren_delicatessen | append: line_item | append: ',' %}
```

Since you can't actually create array with liquid, you need to add a string instead of an object.

```
{% assign kaas_vleeswaren_delicatessen = "" %}

{% for line_item in order.line_items %}
  {% for tag in line_item.product.tags %}
    {% if tag == 'Kaas - vleeswaren - delicatessen Albert Heijn' %}
      {% assign kaas_vleeswaren_delicatessen = kaas_vleeswaren_delicatessen | append: line_item.title | append: ',' %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

{% assign kaas_vleeswaren_delicatessen = kaas_vleeswaren_delicatessen | split: ',' %}

{% for line_item_title in kaas_vleeswaren_delicatessen %}
  {{ line_item_title }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Although it might work a bit better just loop through it and print the values

```
{% for line_item in order.line_items %}
  {% for tag in line_item.product.tags %}
    {% if tag == 'Kaas - vleeswaren - delicatessen Albert Heijn' %}
      {{ line_item.product.title }}
      {{ line_item.product.price }}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```